# What is the utility of split editor with same code in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm currently working with VS Code. It has an option, located on the top-right of the screen, that allows you to split the editor. I'm wondering what is the utility of splitting an editor with the same file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Editor Groups**

This feature allows you to create multiple "editor groups".

The default functionality of the UI option you're referring to, is to open the active editor in a new editor group.

One potential use case for this would be to simultaneously view and edit multiple places in one large file.

**Multiple Files**

However, you can also drag different files into this new editor group — allowing you to view and edit different files at the same time — which is very useful when you have very modularized code (which usually means there's a lot of related code in different files).

You can create virtually unlimited editor groups, and have virtually an unlimited number of files in each group.

**Variety of Layouts**

Additionally, with the latest version of VS Code, you can create two by two grid editor layouts, or create your own custom layout and attach it to a keybinding for easy switching.

**Keybindings**

Editor groups and their files can be controlled with the mouse (click, drag and drop), but you'll end up being a lot more productive if you make an effort to learn the keyboard shortcuts for the commands that you use most often.